# Adding value to a nested python dictionary ? difference between initializations.

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I noticed a bug in my code, and it came from how I had initialized the dictionary. I wrote a sample code to present the issue I faced:

```
ts_dic1= {'a':{'1':0,'2':0},'b':{'1':0,'2':0}}
ts_dic=dict.fromkeys(['a','b'],dict.fromkeys(['1','2'],0))
print ts_dic1
print ts_dic
ts_dic1['a']['1']=1
ts_dic['a']['1']=1
print ts_dic1
print ts_dic
```

I used the initialization as shown in ts_dic in my code which caused the values to be updated across all level 1 keys. I am curious, why python has this behavior, and what would be its use case ?

Comment: Because all values point to the same object in `ts_dic`, for mutable objects any change will be reflected across all keys. Why do you think Python should create a copy?

Answer (score 0):

In the case of

```
ts_dic=dict.fromkeys(['a','b'],dict.fromkeys(['1','2'],0))
```

What the control flow is that python instantiates a dictionary from the internal call

```
 dict.fromkeys(['1','2'],0)
```

This dictionary is then put as value for both the keys. The object reference is same for both, i.e. `ts_dic['a']` and `ts_dic['b']` are pointing to the same address in memory. Thus any modification to `ts_dic['a']` will modify the `ts_dic['b']` as they are actually at the same address in memory. You can check it by using `id()` function on both. `id()` gives the memory address of an object.

```
print(id(ts_dic['a'])) #1
print(id(ts_dic['b'])) #2
print(id(ts_dic1['a'])) #3
print(id(ts_dic1['b'])) #4
```

You will find that #1 and #2 will output the same value.

Answer (score 0):

fromkeys() method is usually used to provide a sequence of keys, and the value to assign to each key.

for example:

t = dict.fromkeys(['a','b','c'], 10)

or you can even use:

t = dict.fromkeys(['a','b','c'], [10,20,30]) then write
t['a'] = [40,50,60] 
and it won't affect key 'b', or 'c'.

But since you have a dictionary, where the object reference is same it is causing the error.